# Connected my sata II SSD using an esata cable, is that correct?

Tags: ssd, sata, cable, esata

I connected my osz vertex 2 using a cable that says eSata on it.

Is this cable correct in terms of giving me the correct amount of throughput?

Is should be able to support 3 GB/s I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eSata?   Are you connecting it externally?

All you need is a regular Sata cable.

Comment: no not externally, internally.  It is the only cable I have.  just want to know if it is going to limit things on my sata ii ssd.

Comment: [WIkipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#eSATA) says "The external connector has no "L"-shaped key, and the guide features are vertically offset and reduced in size. This prevents the use of unshielded internal cables in external applications and vice-versa."

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I figured he has a regular Sata cable, since it is uncommon to "accidentally" buy an eSata cable. Vice versa is more common.

Comment: @codecompleting: I assume you are user27449 and by "board" you mean motherboard. If the cable's connectors fit you should be OK for 3 GB/s (assuming controller and device support it).